# How to write Concatenate url nd text in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I am printing some **url** which is coming dynamic in **phpexcel**

```
$sheet->setCellValue('M'.($results+2),($result['headline']).$result['url']);
```

but the output is like this **`Govt to start Air India roadshows in Singapore this weekhttp://www.windowtonews.com/news.php?id=288115`**

How can i write so that link comes on text with **hyperlink**

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23100636/1483629

Comment: sorry but it  is not duplicate question as url is dynamic also i am using setCellValue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel - How to set a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100636/phpexcel-how-to-set-a-url)

Comment: Your question is in fact a duplicate. Just because the answer happened to use a hard coded value doesn't mean it won't work with a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in three steps:

- set cell value
- set datatype of this cell to `string2`
- set url link to this text value

```
$sheet->setCellValue('M'.($results+2),$result['headline']);
$sheet->getCell('M'.($results+2))->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING2);
$sheet->getCell('M'.($results+2))->getHyperlink()->setUrl(strip_tags($result['url']));
```

In one line it would looks like:

```
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('M'.($results+2), $result['headline'], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING2, TRUE)
      ->getHyperlink()
      ->setUrl(strip_tags($result['url']));
```

*setCellValueExplicit()* - similar to getCell(), if setted to `true` returns the cell instead of the sheet (similar to getActiveSheet()).