# Exporting CSV or EXCEL in Js Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable in my website and I want carry out certain actions like exporting csv, excel, printing, etc. but certain values in the table appear as icons thereby making datatable not to export the values.

here an example

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Name: Sammy</td>
      <td>email: Sammy@mail.com</td>
      <td><a href="https://instagram.com/sammy"><i class="fas fa-instagram"></i></a></td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

So now when I try to export, I want the Instagram link exported too. but Datatable does not capture that. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Default export only supports two different formats i.e., **Numbers** and **InlineString**

To resolved this issue there are many ways and alternatives, you may try any of them which are as follows:

- Try to adjust the exports using the `customize` options provided by the datatTables [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelTextBold.html)

Try this code for `customize` options,

```
customize: function(xlsx) {
    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    // Loop over all cells in sheet
    $('row c', sheet).each( function () {
        // if cell starts with http
        if ($('is t', this).text().indexOf("http") === 0) {
            // (2.) change the type to `str` which is a formula
            $(this).attr('t', 'str');
            //append the formula
            $(this).append('<f>' + 'HYPERLINK("'+$('is t', this).text()+'","'+$('is t', this).text()+'")'+ '</f>');
            //remove the inlineStr
            $('is', this).remove();
            // (3.) underline
            $(this).attr( 's', '4' );
        }
    });
}
```

- You may try with the `HYPERLINK` formula using the [hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet)
- You may also try with the different export options which can be found on the threads [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/56110/how-to-copy-hyperlinks-from-datatable-and-paste-the-values-in-csv-or-excel#Comment_151251) and [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32410/export-hyperlinks-to-copy-csv-or-excel#Comment_104775)
- If these all options do not work then you may also try with the [PHPExcel ref by dataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46837/exporting-url-to-excel) for export options, Here is the stackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100636/phpexcel-how-to-set-a-url)

Hope this helps...